# How to access with a link, any item in dom-repeat

Tags: hyperlink, polymer

I have `dom-repeat` element and listing some items, (height:350px cartoons). I can give unique id while rendering the items. Everything is working perfectly. I wonder, How to access with a link, any item in dom-repeat, that I know the id. something like `jobijoy.com/dashboard#-KwxUEjy2vl_XPkOXo3j` to able to access directly to the item.

**EDIT :** jobijoy.com/dashboard#-KwxUEjy2vl_XPkOXo3j does not work.

```
<template id="document" is="dom-repeat" items="{{qdashboard}}" sort='showLastItemOnTop' rendered-item-count="{{renItemCount}}">
      <div class="liste" id="{{item.key}}"> // id="-KwxUEjy2vl_XPkOXo3j"
        ...  
      </div>
</template>
```

Not: `jobijoy.com` is live and can check there how its look like)

Comment: I haven't tried this within a dom-repeat context myself, but you could try creating <a/>s  with your known IDs and use the URL hash in its classic sense.

Comment: @craPkit, thanks for reply but its not working I tested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the div you are using with an anchor and set the href to the required url.

If the id of the item you want is in the 'key' property you can use:

```
<template id="document" is="dom-repeat" items="{{qdashboard}}" sort='showLastItemOnTop' rendered-item-count="{{renItemCount}}">
    <a href="jobijoy.com/dashboard#{{item.key}}">
      <div class="liste" id="{{item.key}}"> // id="-KwxUEjy2vl_XPkOXo3j"
        ...  
      </div>
    </a>
</template>
```

Comment: No, I need to access item in dom-repeat,  with a link from outside. Not assign a link to each item. So when I click above link you provided will go itself. Please try to understand.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't described that it was a link from outside on the original question.
But either way if you know the link you could just use that link in the href for the anchor.
If the value for the link is stored in a variable you could access it with the double brackets, as it was accessed the property {{item.name}} but with the variable name.
If it's a static link you could just type it.

Comment: thanks for a reply for this is not working. Sorry for my English that I could not explain very well.